# Pull prices on a webpage as well as each prices' font size

Tags: jquery, regex

I am creating a bookmarklet in jquery that should be able to find prices on a page and pull the font size that each price is being displaced. My biggest difficulty is finding a way to use :contains with a regex. It appears :contains can only be used with exact text. 
This is what I have started with. Essentially I would like to go price by price and get the font size with it.

```
jQuery(":contains('" + jQuery('body').text().match(/[$€£]\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})?(\.\d{2})?/g)+ "')").each( function() { 
var size = parseInt( jQuery(this).css( 'fontSize' ), 10 ); 
results.push({ size: size, price: price}); 
});
```

Comment: Why not get each element with `$` or `€` or `£` and then run a regex with `$.grep()` or `$.filter()`?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Perhaps you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @icktoofay - I was going to workup a demo, but I am to wong foo with bookmarklets. Would a jsFiddle test be sufficient?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: I'm not the person that asked the question, so I can't directly answer that, but I think that that would be fine; bookmarklets are just minified JavaScript that's then URL encoded and appended to `javascript:`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you could get a result by searching for the currency symbols first, then, `$.grep()` or `$.filter()` with the regex. Let me put a jsFiddle together to demonstration (I don't every bookmarklet, so I'm not sure how to reference jQuery from within one).

**EDIT 2**

The following attempts to get the most inner element `$.text()` and ignore parent elements. Again, I suspect the method doesn't perfectly handle something like a paragraph tag with multiple inner elements, both having price strings. But it is further along than what is below.

You'll see something in the fiddle a little more verbose, but the following is the part that makes it work.

```
function containsSelector(value) {
  return ':contains(' + value + ')';
}

function groupContainsSelector(list) {
  return $.map(list, containsSelector).join(',');
}

function groupExpression(list) {
  var expression = '[' + list.join('') + ']\\d{1,3}(,?\\d{3})?(\\.\\d{2})?';

  if (!expressions.hasOwnProperty(expression)) {
    expressions[expression] = new RegExp(expression, 'g');
  }

  return expressions[expression];
}
```

Note that I cache the `RegExp`, so I'm not calling for a new one that I've already created.

```
function hasCurrency($el, currency, test) {
  if ($el.children(currency).size()) {
    return false;
  }

  return !!$el.text().match(test);
}
```

Using those functions, we can use one of the following, depending on the situation:

```
$contains = $(currencieselector, document.body);

$filter = $contains.filter(function (i, el) {
  return hasCurrency($(el), currencieselector, groupexp);
});

$grep = $.grep($contains, function (el, i) {
  return hasCurrency($(el), currencieselector, groupexp);
});

$map = $contains.map(function () {
  return !hasCurrency($(this), currencieselector, groupexp) || this;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/CvYpx/9/

I use a `setTimeout` to apply each layer of styling applied to the elements found in each method. Other than `$contains`, the other three are the same result. I also highlight each denomination:

```
$.each(currencies, function (index, val) {
  $contains.filter(function (i, el) {
    return hasCurrency($(el), containsSelector(val), groupExpression([val]));
  })
  .addClass(denominations[index]);
});
```

**EDIT**

Here is more or less what I was getting at, with some contrived examples:

```
<p>Franc: £58,00</p>
<aside>No price</aside>
<p>Dollar: $8.08</p>
<p>Euro: €5.34</p>
<p>No price</p>
<p>SPAN price: <span>€3,00</span></p>
<p>STRONG: <strong>£73.93</strong></p>
<p>EM: <em>$73.93</em></p>

var $contains = $(':contains($),:contains(€),:contains(£)', document.body),
    regex = /[$€£]\d{1,3}(,?\d{3})?(\.\d{2})?/g,
    $filter,
    $grep;

$grep = $.grep($contains, function(n, i){
    console.log($(n).text().match(regex), $(n).text());
    return !!$(n).text().match(regex);
});

$filter = $contains.filter(function(n, i){
    console.log($(i).text().match(regex));
    return !!$(i).text().match(regex);
});

console.log($contains);
console.log($filter);
console.log($grep);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/CvYpx/

Note, there's an issue of finding both a `parent` and a `child` in the result, which I'm not sure if you're wanting to do that or not. Also, the regex I'm not great at, so no comment. So it's not perfect, but it's the general idea with `$.grep()` and `$.filter()`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider a different way to do it: get all of the text nodes on the page, and for each one that matches your regular expression, get the font size of the computed style of the parent node. This may seem inefficient, but in fact, it is not: jQuery already has to do something similar to evaluate your `contains` query.